# Deleting user in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete user through menu as you see below:

[image]

and then I get this error:

[image]

what is the problem? how can I fix it?

Comment: Find scheme owned by user `babi`, change ownership then delete user.

Comment: google the last line in that error message.. there is a bit of common sense that comes into play here.. also if you are not able to do a google search.. Contact your DBA..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the authorizations user had and

```
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.schemas s
WHERE s.principal_id = USER_ID('babi');
```

and then

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_denydatareader or db_denydatawriter TO dbo;
```

it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, schemas are real entities. You cannot drop a user that owns schemas; you first have to either drop the schemas or change their owner to be another user.

Please refer the below link:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/12/26/sql-server-fix-error-15138-the-database-principal-owns-a-schema-in-the-database-and-cannot-be-dropped/